# Google warning about SSL/TLS certificate

Tags: https, no-www

I received this warning from Google Webmaster Tools. I have SSL for `www` and non-`www` but they are in different SANS. Would that cause a problem?

> SSL/TLS certificate does not include domain name `https://www.example.com/`
>
> Google has detected that the current SSL/TLS certificate used on ... does not include ... domain name. This means that your website is not perceived as secure by some browsers. As a result, many web browsers will block users accessing your site by displaying a security warning message. This is done to protect users’ browsing behavior from being intercepted by a third party, which can happen on sites that are not secure.

Answer (score 1):

Just saying your SSL Certificate does not bear your domain name which most browsers won't load it. Called Common Name

> The Common Name is typically composed of Host + Domain Name and will
>   look like "www.yoursite.com" or "yoursite.com". SSL Server
>   Certificates are specific to the Common Name that they have been
>   issued to at the Host level. The Common Name must be the same as the
>   Web address you will be accessing when connecting to a secure site.
>   For example, a SSL Server Certificate for the domain "domain.com" will
>   receive a warning if accessing a site named "www.domain.com" or
>   "secure.domain.com", as "www.domain.com" and "secure.domain.com" are
>   different from "domain.com". You would need to create a CSR for the
>   correct Common Name. When the Certificate will be used on an Intranet
>   (or internal network), the Common Name may be one word, and it can
>   also be the name of the server.

[More info](http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=10048)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i still have questions. Well, i have 60 domains and bought 2 different certificates, one for www and one for non-www. Since all 60 domains in the SAN there is only 1 domain which matches to Common Name. so i will get this warning from google for 59domains ? Will eveyone who uses SAN for multiple domain get the same warning from Google?

Comment: No, SAN is Subject Alternative Name - used for adding multiple Common Names to a certificate. If the domains are in SAN; they won't receive warning.

Comment: I see the same Common Name when i check other domains in the SAN. If the hosting  company made a misteke when they installed certificate within server? or the problem is related with CSR?

Comment: You'll see same CN but different SAN